# Send Push Notification using Urban Airship in Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, push-notification, urbanairship.com

I'm trying to send push notifications using Urban 
Airship. My app is developed in unity(Android).
So far I've done this.

- Created an app on Urban Airship (dev mode).
- Integrated sdk in unity
- Added App-key and App-secret to Unity App
- Compsed a message targetting all devices

But the message did not show up (I chose to send it immediately)
Is there anything missing, like attatching some script to scene?
The documentation is not of great help in this regard

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are using the [Urban Airship Unity plugin](http://docs.urbanairship.com/platform/unity.htm), you also need to [enable user notification.](http://docs.urbanairship.com/platform/unity.html#enabling-user-notifications)